# Polish citizen flying from Canada to Honolulu with a layover in Chicago

Tags: customs-and-immigration, layovers

My parents are Polish and are traveling from Canada to Honolulu with a layover in Chicago. they arrive in Canada from Poland a day later. do they need to go through passport check and baggage/customs in Chicago, or only at their destination in Honolulu?

Comment: Welcome to travel.stackexchange!

Answer (score 12):

If your parents are flying from Calgary, Edmonton, Halifax, Montréal Trudeau, Ottawa, Toronto Pearson, Vancouver, or Winnipeg, they will have the immigration check in Canada before they leave. If they are flying from another Canadian airport, they will have the immigration check in Chicago. In no case would they have any immigration formalities in Honolulu.